# How to make a proper JFrame in Java Language?

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe

> > Hello community! I am very new to Java language and need help to make JFrame
> >     work. I believe that the code posted below is wrong as it terminates. I am using the text editor Eclipse. Please help as I cannot find what the problem is. Thanks!

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Game extends JFrame {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public void run(){
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("Good");
    setSize(900,500);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {


}

 }
```

Comment: could you please paste the error/debug info

Comment: Thanks but my question has been answered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case main() method should look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Game game = new Game();
game.run(); 
}
```